# Unable to open website in Firefox using selenium webdriver one updated version to 55

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefoxdriver

Here is the sample code which I'm using.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://google.com");
```

I'm facing problem since i have updated it to latest version i.e. v55.

I am getting below error:

> 1503742678555 addons.xpi  WARN    Error parsing extensions state:
>   [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012
>   (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [amIAddonManagerStartup.readStartupData]" 
>   nsresult: "0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)"  location: "JS frame
>   :: resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm :: loadExtensionState
>   :: line 1596"  data: no] Stack trace:
>   loadExtensionState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1596
>   < getInstallState()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:1631
>   < checkForChanges()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:3152
>   < startup()@resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm:2246 <
>   callProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:271 <
>   _startProvider()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:741 < startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:908 <
>   startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3122 <
>   observe()@jar:file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Mozilla%20Firefox/omni.ja!/components/addonManager.js:65

Comment: Whenever there is an issue like this, the first thing to check is that you have the latest version of FF, geckodriver, AND selenium. If that doesn't fix it then there might be a bug in the geckodriver that you can search for or log. Reverting to an older version may be the only option until it gets fixed (which usually happens pretty fast).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.