# NoSuchElementException when opening dropdown

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I am a newbie to Selenium. I am running a script which opens Static dropdown but it is providing error. Could anyone please help me out?

My code:

```
package basics;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SpiceJetWebUIControls {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","N://drivers//geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://spicejet.com/");
        Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ct100_mainContent_dd1_Adult")));

        s.selectByValue("2");
        s.selectByIndex(6);
        s.selectByVisibleText("9 Adults");
    }

}
```

Error provided:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
>   Unable to locate element: #ct100_mainContent_dd1_Adult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `By.id()` is wrong. I visited the site, looked at the sources and you used **DD1** while the site uses **DDL** in their id. (ct**1**00_mainContent_dd**1**_Adult vs ct**l**00_mainContent_dd**l**_Adult)

In some fonts the 1 and l look very similar. Make a habit of using cut and paste and try to minimize the code you type manually. This is very important for variables-, function-, class-names and webdriver selectors.

`NoSuchElementException` means that the element does not exist at the time you try to access it. It could have multiple reasons:

- Wrong selector (this is your case I think)
- Not yet there: The page is still loading. Use the [WebDriver wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736027/webdriver-wait-for-element-using-java) to wait for the element to appear.
- Disappeared: Was there, but when you try to use it is gone.

Comment: Yes,I found that that the error is specific to site as it worked for other sites for me.Thankyou soo much for identifying.Got it.

Comment: I tried again with the modified code and got an error- Error parsing extensions state: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)

Comment: Hmm not sure, better ask a new question. Googling resulted in some people suggestion to upgrade everything to the latest version. https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/29223/unable-to-open-website-in-firefox-using-selenium-webdriver-one-updated-version-t